# Stock Android Emojis Image DL

Tags: android, graphics, emoji

I'd like to use try and use stock android emojis to build a pixel image using emojis as pixels that I've rated based on color or brightness and assign one per image pixel that nearest matches.

How do I access the stock android images of these emojis?, I find lots of crappy compressed pixelated versions on google images but I'd like to work with the stock unmodified image data.

They must be buried somewhere on my phone or within android image/source.

Accepting all and any pointers :)

Thx!

Tony

Comment: hmmm... https://emojipedia.org

Comment: Realize that Android has a [Emoji Compat library](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/text-and-emoji/emoji2) and uses font renderering to show the various icons.